# htaccess - Understanding the different between two RewriteCond conditions

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would be so appreciative if somebody would explain the differences between the Condition 1 and Condition 2 for the below htaccess code.

Condition 1

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Condition 2

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is for your rules is that you don't need 2 rules to accomplish the same goal. They both redirect to https version of your site, so you can combine the conditions using `[OR]`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

So that will redirect anything that is not http to https without www (or any other subdomain). And redirect www to non www with https. 2 conditions same rule.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer. also, how can I add a `/` to the end of url if the url is not a file and does not already have an `/` at the end with your code?

Comment: I replaced the code online, however it is not working for `http://domain.com/jobs` or `http://www.domain.com/jobs`, any suggestion?